# What is the correct way to manage subdomains without VirtualHost conflicts?

Tags: apache

I am using Apache 2.2 on CentOS. I have set the correct DNS records.

By default, my Apache is serving from `/var/www/html` without any VirtualHosts set up at all. I would like to serve something else, say `/var/www/html/bakery`, when a request for `bakery.myfakesite.com` comes in, but continue to serve the default folder for plain `myfakesite.com` requests.

To this end, I wrote in httpd.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myfakesite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName bakery.myfakesite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/bakery
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem is that this results in a conflict, where only the first virtualhost is actually used. I've done something wrong, but I'm not quite sure what. What should I be doing instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be a

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

right before your vhost definitions

that means "hey, I want you to match requests comparing their http_host with the serverName in the following vhosts, instead of just sending everything to the first one that matches IP and port".